# Positioning sibling-elements to same bottom on hover (parent has no fixed height)

Tags: php, css, sass, position, omeka

[image]

So I have something that looks like this atm

These thumbnails & titles come from a database (used with omeka).
What I want is the titles bottom (which varies from size of the title), to be equal to the thumbnails bottom, so the title is some kind of 'overlay'.

To make it even more perfect I would want this only to be visible at thumbnail-hover & to come in from the bottom as a little animation.

In the DOM, this looks like

```
  <div class='col-3 collection-item'>
      <a href="link"><img/></a>
      <p class="collection-item-title"></p>
  </div>
```

In my code it is called by

```
<?php if (metadata('collection', 'total_items') > 0): ?>
<?php foreach (loop('items') as $item): ?>
<div class="col-3 collection-item">
  <?php if (metadata('item', 'has thumbnail')): ?>
   <?php echo link_to_item(item_image('square_thumbnail', array('alt' => $itemTitle))); ?>
   <p class="collection-item-title"><?php echo $itemTitle; ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach>
<?php endif>
```

How would I handle this best - with Sass (css) - since all sizes (both thumbnail and title) vary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if i did understand correctly what you want to achieve this might be the solution

```
.collection-item {
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.collection-item-title {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(blue, .4);
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform:translate(0%, 100%); //move it down by 100% of its _own_ height
  transition: transform .4s ease-in-out .2s;
}
.collection-item:hover .collection-item-title {
  transform:translate(0%, 0%); //move it back up
  transition: transform .4s ease-in-out .2s;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPegOq

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
}
.thumb-block{
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.team-section figure:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/StyleSheet1.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="team-section">
    <figure class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" >
        <div class="thumb-block">
            <img src="../images/aa.jpg" style="height:20%; width:100%">
        </div>
        <figcaption>
           
            <p>
                your text here
            </p>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumb-block">
            <img src="../images/aa.jpg" style="height:20%; width:100%">
        </div>
        <figcaption>

            <p>
                your text here
            </p>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumb-block">
            <img src="../images/aa.jpg" style="height:20%; width:100%">
        </div>
        <figcaption>

            <p>
                your text here
            </p>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

give hight and width to img and also to parent div of img and title

```css
.sync
{
height:30%;
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-3 collection-item sync'>
      <a href="link"><img/></a>
      <p class="collection-item-title"></p>
  </div>
```